# How does a Silicon-Controlled Rectifier (SCRs) work?

Tags: semiconductors, how-does-it-work, scr

I know that when in a SCR the anode is made more positive with respect to cathode the two outermost p-n junction get forward-biased but the middle one is still reverse-biased  so no current flows through it but when a small gate current is applied to it the middle junction also get forward-biased and allows a huge amount of current to flow through it but in my text book it is not described at the atomic level what happens it is only it's working stated. Can anyone give an explanation of what is going on the atomic level.

Thanks

Akash

Comment: Check out these two pages which show you how to create an SCR from typical transistors.  As long as you understand how a transistor works at the atomic level these pages should enlighten you on how the SCR works at an atomic level.  Once you've read them come back and ask a more specific question if you still don't understand. http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_3/chpt_7/3.html and http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_3/chpt_7/5.html